# Trying to get python to run a program in terminal and output to a file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Here's what I've got so far...

```
import os
os.system("lxterminal --command='sudo netdiscover -p -PL >> 
/home/pi/data.txt'")
```

The issue that I'm having is when I execute this code it doesn't write out to a file like it would if I just put it into a terminal window. Instead, it opens two terminal windows, one titled sh that shows that the code executed without a problem, followed by a second one titled data.txt that does nothing. Removing the single quotes from before sudo and after txt causes it to write out to a file, but only to tell me how to use commands with the LXTerminal. How can I make it write out and append to a file (called anything, doesn't have to be data.txt)?

Comment: Don't use `os.system` it's pretty old and sometimes doesn't work for what you need it to do. Try using `subprocess.popen` instead.

Comment: None of this requires a terminal. Just run the command itself in a subprocess.

Comment: @MustacheMoses, thank you for telling me about `subprocess.popen` and @tripleee thank you for showing me it didn't need to be in a terminal window to work, thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(args=["xterm", "-e", "/bin/echo hi >> /home/user/data.txt"], shell=True)
```

Comment: I had to play around with this a little bit, but ultimately it worked perfectly, thank you very much, I appreciate the help!